# How to rotate a circle-sector across its pivot (as circle center) in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can you rotate a circle-sector (or a segment) across its pivot (circle center)?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rotate(60 * Math.PI / 180); // wrong rotation
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, (1/12) * 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 75);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.

Rotating a drawn object can be done with `arc` itself as its the fourth param of it. This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) might help you as well.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var startAngle = 0;
var rotatedAngle = 60;

function degtorat (deg){
  return deg * Math.PI/180;
}

// degtorat2 looks odd in the first glance but it is not because PI
// is also used as counter variable with deg no matter whether is's 
// put after the division
// -> (deg * PI) / 180 as in degtorat   
function degtorat2 (deg){
  return deg / 180 * Math.PI;
}

setInterval(function(){

  ctx.beginPath();
  // ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
  // endangle must also be increased by the same amount of startAngle
  ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, degtorat(startAngle), degtorat(startAngle)+(1/12) * 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.lineTo(100,75);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  // increase angle at 60 degrees  
  startAngle += rotatedAngle;

},1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

---

As requested a short explanation of these operations `degtorat(startAngle)+(1/12) * 2 * Math.PI`, step by step:

The whole equation returns the endAngle in radians to which a triangle is drawn.

Lets split this up:

1. `degtorat(startAngle)`:

   We want to draw a triangle starting at a certain `startAngle` in clockwise direction, therefore we have to start at this angle as well. But this is not enough because a triangle should have a certain size as well. So here `(1/12) * 2 * Math.PI` comes into play.

   Spoiler: `degtorat` converts (mostly used by humans) degrees to radians (always used by HTML5 canvas-context operations). (I just added `degtorat` `degtorat2` to prove that no matter whether PI is multiplied before or after the devision the right radian is always returned.)
2. `(1/12) * 2 * Math.PI`:

   These operations must be added to the `degtorat(startAngle)` because a triangle should have a certain size. To calculate this size we use these operations  `(1/12) * 2 * Math.PI`.

   `2 * Math.PI` represents a whole circle in radians. A circle can contain 12 triangles each with a size of 30 degrees, but we can only draw 6 triangles because we leave 30 degrees blank. So thats why we have to divide the whole circle by 12 (`(1/12)`, 6 visible triangles, 6 blank triangles).

   But we want to rotate a visible triangle by 60 degrees as well. So after the first visible triangle is drawn that fills up 30 degrees of the whole circle, we increase the `startAngle` by 60 degrees to start drawing the next triangle 60 degrees after the first `startAngle` and leaving 30 degrees blank.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! )))

Comment: You are weolcome :)

Comment: Can you explain degtorat(startAngle)+(1/12) * 2 * Math.PI